# JWrapper How Does The Memory Work?

Tags: memory-management, jwrapper

I'm after a bit of info on how JWrapper uses memory on the client. We've got a 3rd party app that we're running through JWrapper. Before moving to JWrapper we had issues with memory leaks so we previously set the runtime memory parameter to Xmx256m in the deployment file. Can I specify how much memory to use in JWrapper?

I genuinely have tried to find this out myself but I can't find anything on the web. I didn't have any choice about getting JWrapper; it just happened to me one day hence I haven't really got much of an idea about it.

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the jvm options in your jwrapper XML config file including -Xmx256m etc, the following sample XML file has an example -Xmx option:

http://www.jwrapper.com/sample-app-xml.html

Comment: Thanks for your help Antony (sorry I've only just seen it as I didn't have email notifications turned on). Having looked at what you've sent would you say that JWrapper uses memory in the same way the JVM does?

Thanks :)